# Android .ogg file stops playing after a few seconds

Tags: android, soundpool, ogg

The music either doesn't even start playing sometimes, but when it does, it stops after a few seconds. The file is 2 minutes long. I really don't know what's the problem.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
music = soundPoolVar.load(this, R.raw.music11, 1);
}
```

then

```
public void soundPlay(int i, MySurface pl, float volume) {
    if (soundOn == true) {
        switch (i) {
case 11:
            soundPoolVar.play(music, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
}}}
```

Comment: Do you use SoundPool for playing long audio files?
I'm surprised that it is working. I think you need to use MediaPlayer (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for playing music. SoundPool using for playing short audio files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundPool designed to play short sound effects. To play music (big audio files) you need to use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

```
// R.raw.audio_file - res/raw/audio_file.mp3

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file);
mediaPlayer.start();
```